# Database table has different schema than model description in Flask application

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, migration

I have an old application that I'm redeploying. The following model class:

```
class TableA(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name_key = db.Column(db.String(20), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    acronym_key = db.Column(db.String(6), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

has the following table in postgres:

```
                                      Table "public.tablea"
   Column    |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |             Default
-------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id          | integer                |           | not null | nextval('tablea_id_seq'::regclass)
 name_key    | character varying(10)  |           | not null |
 acronym_key | character varying(6)   |           | not null |
```

Notice the length of the column `name_key`, it does not match.

As I worked in this when I still didn't know what I was doing with the migrations, I double checked if I had left changes that were not saved as migrations, with 
`flask db migrate` and `flask db upgrade`. I got some changes to the db, but not this one. Do column lengths do not generate migration changes? What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Might this be the answer? http://blog.code4hire.com/2017/06/setting-up-alembic-to-detect-the-column-length-change/

Comment: Perfect @PetrBlahos, you should have added it as an answer! Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't really as I cannot add more details, because I do not use flask. If you feel like, write the answer yourself, ideally with pointing the places in configuration that need to be changed, and I will gladly accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @PeterBlahos' link, alembic needs to be configured to notice differences in column lengths.

For that you need to modify `{project-root}/migrations/env.py`, modify the run_migrations_* methods context.configure segments by adding the compare_type=True as in the snippet bellow:

```
def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url, target_metadata=target_metadata, literal_binds=True, compare_type=True)

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool)

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            compare_type=True
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

After that just run on your terminal `flask db migrate -m "some explanation for the changes"` to create the migration file and `flask db upgrade` for the changes to actually affect the db.

Big thanks to @PeterBlahos who actually answered 85% of the question :).